# How do I interpret $f=\{1+o(1)\}\phi$?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

> Prove: If $f$~$\phi$, then $f=\{1+o(1)\}\phi$

How do I interpret $f=\{1+o(1)\}\phi$?

I'm particularly confused because usually we write $f=o(1)$ when $f$ vanishes as $x\to\infty$ but in this case I'm not sure if I should say "$f$ is ANY FUNCTION that is the product of $\phi$ with the addition of $1$ and the CLASS of functions which vanish as $x$ tends to infinity." Are we allowed to divide both sides by $\phi$ and subtract $1$?

Since I don't understand what the equation exactly means, for proving the claim, I'm not sure if I should deal with when $\phi$ is zero, or $\phi$ tends to zero. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Something more or less like this: There is some function $g$ such that $f=\{1+g\}\phi$ and $g=o(1)$

Comment: That makes very much sense. But I started confusing myself and overthinking since I saw that the equation here is really one directional. Like, I can write $o(f)=O(f)$ but not $O(f)=o(f)$. Maybe following your explanation, I am allowed to switch $g$ to the left hand side of the equation, but it seems that by doing so, I would violate the unidirectionality of $o$ notation and doesn't seem right. So what if, say, there is small $o$ notation on the both sides of the equation?

Comment: Yeah typically you see people try to avoid putting orders on the left-most side because they introduce ambiguities that you mentioned, i.e. $o(f)=O(f)$ will be spelled out as "if $g=o(f)$ then $g=O(f)$". Although $g=o(f)=O(f)$ is allowed because it implies that logical deduction. If you see any source or author who does otherwise, then I'd suggest studying the way they introduced that notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given equation means that the difference of $f$ and $\phi$ becomes negligible with respect to $\phi$ as $x\to\infty$. In mathematical terms, this means that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)-\phi(x)}{\phi(x)}=0
\end{equation}
As a concrete example, think of $f(x) = x$ and $\phi(x)=x+\dfrac1x$. So $f$ is asymptotically "like" $\phi(x)$.

Also note that the difference of $f$ and $\phi$ becomes negligible with respect to $f$ as well, since,

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)-\phi(x)}{f(x)}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)-\phi(x)}{f(x)-\phi(x)+\phi(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\ \dfrac{f(x)-\phi(x)}{\phi(x)}\ }{\ \dfrac{f(x)-\phi(x)}{\phi(x)}+1}\\
&=0
\end{align}

As another example, you can take $f(x)=x$ and $\phi(x)=x+\log x$. Here the difference of $f$ and $\phi$ is itself unbounded asymptotically, but still $f$ is "like" $\phi$ as $x$ grows large.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know what the given equation is equivalent to in terms of algebraic interpretation

Comment: @able20, I've given an example which is concrete in my sense. What is your sense of the word?

Comment: I wanted to know what the algebraic interpretation is, so that I can also apply it to more complicated case, such as $e^{ix}\{1+o(1)\}+e^{-ix}\{1+o(1)\}=2cos x+o(1)$

Comment: The example you gave is very easy, just distribute the products on LHS, and note that $|e^{ix}+e^{-ix}|$ is bounded by $2$, so $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})o(1)=o(1)$.

Comment: Is the above equation equivalent to saying that $e^{ix}\{1+o(1)\}+e^{-ix}\{1+o(1)\}=2cosx+g(x)$ for some $g(x)=o(1)$?

Comment: Yes @able20, it is equivalent to saying that.

Comment: And it's not to say that $e^{ix}\{1+f(x)\}+e^{-ix}\{1+g(x)\}=2cosx+h(x)$ for some $f,g,h=o(1)$? Sorry but it's the point that I was confused about

Comment: @able20, You can say that also, since $h(x)=e^{ix}f(x)+e^{-ix}g(x)$, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}|h(x)| \le \lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|+ \lim_{x\to\infty}|g(x)|=0$. Therefore, given that $f$ and $g$ are $o(1)$, $h$ is also $o(1)$.

Comment: Then can we say that, whenever we encounter big O or small o, we substitute them with some arbitrary function, set them equal, and say that those functions are estimated to whatever O we substituted with? I was confused because there can be ambiguity, for example we cannot say $O(1)=o(1)$ but we can say $o(1)=O(1)$. Following the above algorithm both can be expressed as $f(x)=g(x)$ for some $f(x)=o(1)$ and $g(x)=O(1)$.

Comment: @able20, You always can't say that `those functions are estimated to whatever O we substituted with`. For example, taking $\log x$ instead of $e^{-ix}$ in above example of yours, it gets unbounded asymptotically, so we can't use comparison test to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}h(x)=0$. So $h(x)$ may not be $o(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $o(f), x \to x_0$ is set of functions:
$$o(f) = \{g \colon \exists \delta>0, \exists \varepsilon(x), \lim\limits_{x \to x_0}\varepsilon(x)=0, \forall x \in U_\delta(x_0), g(x)= \varepsilon(x) \cdot f(x) \}$$

So, $f=\{1+o(1)\}\phi \Leftrightarrow f-\phi = o(\phi)$ means, that $f-\phi = \phi \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon \to 0$.  Say strictly $f-\phi \in o(\phi)$.

Answering your question generally $\phi$ can have zeros in $U_\delta(x_0)$, which means we cannot divide both sides on $\phi$. For sure we can say only that if holds $f=\{1+o(1)\}\phi$, then  $f-\phi$ have same zeros as $\phi$.